PnP PowerShell MFA Issue - Set Access Request Email
I'm trying to set Access Request email as Site Owner for all site collections in our M365 tenant using PnP PowerShell command:
Set-PnPRequestAccessEmails -Disabled:$false

However I see that using Connect-PnPOnline I have to authenticate for each site collection as the support account is MFA enabled. I tried return connection but when I used that to fetch a site I get prompted again for credentials.
For example, I first connected using:
$connection = Connect-PnPOnline -url https://mytenant-admin.sharepoint.com  -Interactive -ReturnConnection

Connect-PnPOnline -url $siteUrl -Connection $connection

But get prompted again for credentials, so I can't use this in a foreach loop as we have 1000s of sites.

I checked the documentation for the authentication and you could perhaps register an Azure AD (Entra ID) app and authenticate using a certificate. https://pnp.github.io/powershell/articles/authentication.html#setting-up-access-to-your-own-azure-ad-app
